# Recursive function returning empty string

Tags: vba, recursion

How do I properly exit a recursive function and return a value in VBA?

I have this simple code to remove multiple spaces from a string:

```vb
Public Function RemoveMultipleSpaces(s As String) As String
    If InStr(1, s, "  ", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
        Dim newS As String
        newS = Replace(s, "  ", " ")
        RemoveMultipleSpaces (newS)
    Else
        RemoveMultipleSpaces = s
        End
    End If
End Function
```

But depending on what I use to exit either `End` or `Exit Function`, I either get nothing returned or an empty string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A proper recursive function doesn't need a specific exit condition. You just stop calling the function recursively, and it exits.

However, if you want to explicitly exit, you can use `Exit Function`.

Your mistake, however, is that when you make a recursive call, you need to return the result of the recursive call.

```vb
Public Function RemoveMultipleSpaces(s As String) As String
    If InStr(1, s, "  ", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
        Dim newS As String
        newS = Replace(s, "  ", " ")
        RemoveMultipleSpaces = RemoveMultipleSpaces(newS)
    Else
        RemoveMultipleSpaces = s
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: Your code modifies the `byref s` as well as returning the result. That is not what the OP had.

Comment: @GSerg Valid, adjusted it to not modify the byref. Note this leads to storing one copy of the string for each level of recursion, which can be a burden on memory when working with large strings.

Comment: Oh, that makes sense! Thank you.